# jQuery ajax infinite scroll duplicate ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, duplicates

I am calling ajax call but when I am scrolling 2 times its calling duplicate ajax calls.. For two scrolls I am getting duplicate ajax call.can anyone help me how to rectify duplicate ajax call.

```
jQuery(function($){       
    $('#infscr-loading').hide();
    $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            var key = $(".tab-content div.active").attr("id"); 
            var offset = $(".tab-content div.active .movie_boot .movie-beta__item").length;
            var data1 = $("#yr").val();             
            url = "/loop-movies/?offset="+offset+'&key='+key+'&yr='+data1;
            $.ajax({
                type       : "post",
                url        : url,
                delay      : 500, 
                beforeSend : function(){
                    $('#infscr-loading').show();
                },
                success    : function(response) {   
                    $(".tab-content div.active .movie_boot").append(response);
                    $('#infscr-loading').hide();
                }
            });         
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you have written ajax call on scroll of window so it will call as many times as you scroll

Comment: I suggest using [infinite](https://github.com/yairEO/infinite) or [endless](https://github.com/yairEO/endless) plugins which are easy to use

Answer (score 1):

```
var flag;
if (flag.readyState == 4 && flag.status == 200) {
  flag = $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    delay: 500,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#infscr-loading').show();
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $(".tab-content div.active .movie_boot").append(response);
      $('#infscr-loading').hide();
    }
  });
}
else{
   alert("AJAX is going on")
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/WQXXT/1425/) to show the working

**[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)**

Comment: @GabrielBenamy ... ha ha... Always glad to hear that `:)`

Answer (score 0):

For achieving that behaviour you don't need to rely on the `onScroll` event all that just with `Vanilla Javascript` and the `IntersectionObserver API`.

All you need to do is place elements and listen for when they become available in the screen and have a global variable (in your scenario) that is switched to `hasMoreItems = true` or `hasMoreItems = false` when it reached the end or it's loading

You can accomplish that with a few javascript & html lines and it's `much more performant` than listening for scroll events in the browsers

I recently put together an article about infinite scrolling and this specific behaviour [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/infinite-scroll-done-the-right-way-33cb7be18407)